# What is this squiggly moving line in the recent SpaceX SARah-1 Mission?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object, debris

I watched the livestream of the launch of the SpaceX SARah-1 Mission.

Shortly after the boostback burn there is this squiggly white line that moves away from the first stage, starting at [T+03:54](https://youtu.be/lCX-KUCn4A4?t=1130). It happens a couple of times during this section of the flight, always from the same spot and angle relative to the stage, even after rotating a lot. A screenshot with obligatory red arrow:

[image: image of the first stage with the squiggly white line]

What is this? A couple of possibilities I see:

- some debris coming loose
- excess fluid being dumped
- camera glare (unlikely because of the angle change)

Comment: The one at [4:14](https://youtu.be/lCX-KUCn4A4?t=1150) is more startling - it "reverses direction" at 4:15 compared to the background & rocket when the thruster fires. Presumably what we see is the whole rocket body translating towards it without much rotation, e.g. a thrusters fired at both ends. Surprises me since I expected the thrusters to be providing rotation to orient the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is so often the case, this is almost certainly ice. There's a vent or umbilical coupling on that side: you can see a few points in the flight where there's fog streaming back from that part of the vehicle, from venting gases, or perhaps boil-off of residual propellant as ambient pressure dropped. And the foggy launch conditions showed there was plenty of water in the air.